# ContentType in a model not being saved correctly

Tags: django

I have a model that is essentially a tag:

```
class Tag( models.Model ):
    tag = models.CharField( max_length=15 )
    text_color = RGBColorField(default='#000000')
    background_color =  RGBColorField( default='#88ff88' )

    entered_by = models.ForeignKey( 'member.Member', related_name='tag_entered_by' )
    entered_on = models.DateTimeField( default=timezone.now )

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name="tag_content_type")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag
```

A few days ago I created a few tags associated with a particular model based on the ContentType.  Everything was working fine and "I didn't change anything".

I then created some Tags from the shell:

```
>> class_object=get_model('call', 'Call')
>> ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(class_object)
>>> tag = Tag(tag='thetag', text_color='#FFFFFF', background_color='#B40303', content_type=ct, entered_by=automem)                                                      
>>> tag.content_type
<ContentType: Call>
>>> tag.save()
>>> tag.content_type
<ContentType: Call>
>>> 
>>> 
>>> ts = Tag.objects.filter(tag='thetag')
>>> for t in ts:
...     print(t.content_type)
... 
invoice
```

The "invoice" is a different model.  So, I don't understand why, in this case, the content_type is not being saved properly.

I am using Django 1.8 and Python 3.4.

[Added]
A little more information:

```
>>> ct
<ContentType: Call>
>>> ct.id
24
```

But when I do this:

```
>>> for t in ContentType.objects.all():
...     print('{} {}'.format(t, t.id))
```

I get

```
...
invoice 24
...
Call 28
...
```

Comment: What is the `len(ts)` in this case?

Comment: In this case len(ts) is 1, which is what I think I would have expected.

Comment: [Now that I think of it, you are wondering if I am looking at the wrong tag.  There is only one 'thetag'].